# Cannot pass value from overloaded operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As stated in topic i have got problem with passing value from overloaded operator back to main function. I have searched for this a lot but with no effect. Here is my sample operator. Line before returning Matrix m i have put cout to check if algorithm works fine. I have got same problem with multiplying operator.

matrix.h

```
class Matrix 
{
public:
...
Matrix &operator+(const Matrix &m)
... 

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    double **tab;

};
```

matrix.cpp

```
Matrix &Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &m)
{
if(x==m.x && y==m.y)
{
    Matrix temp(x,y);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            temp.tab[i][j]=tab[i][j]+m.tab[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << temp<< endl;
return temp;
}
else
{
    char er[]={"error!\n"};
    throw er;
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [return value of operator overloading in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c)

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local variable (`temp`, right :-). It has already been destroyed when you return to main. Return by value instead.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for Your help You were right! I had stupid mistake in copy constructor that's why no matter what was coppied to main function I had matrix filled with 0 as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that an addition operator should not return a reference, but a value:

```
Matrix operator+(const Matrix &m);
```

This applies to multiplication, subtraction, etc.

Besides the fact that you are returning a reference to a variable that only exists in the scope of the function, it wouldn't make sense semantically to return a reference. Think of this expression:

```
B + C;
```

If it were to return a reference, what should it refer to?

A common approach is to implement `Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix&)` as a member operator, and then implement addition as a non-member:

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix lhs, const Matrix& rhs)
{
  return lhs += rhs;
}
```

This makes the operation symmetric WRT the LHS and the RHS, allowing for implicit conversions on both sides.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are right but when I change it my problem still occurs. Now when i try to cout Matrix in main function it is filled with zero values

Comment: @Norrec then you have some other problem in your code you did not show us.

Comment: @Norrec It is difficult to see from the code you posted, but there could be something wrong with your constructors.

Comment: @juanchopanza I will try to repair this functions basing on Your hints. At least thanks to You I know where I should look for mistakes in code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: never ever return references to objects you create in a function. Meaning, your operator should return a `Matrix`, not a `Matrix&` (the `&` belongs to the return type, you might want to put it there to make it more obvious).

If you provide a proper move constructor for your Matrix class, there will be no expensive copy on returning the result.