# C++: Strange vector behavior

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

While writing code for my assignment, I have stuck on one strange behavior. The code is big, so while it is not necessary, I won't post it.

The thing is while I was trying to delete an object from the vector, I had a segmentation fault. While trying to debug it myself, I have found this:

If I execute my code with the following snippet, I have my vector empty and then segmentation fault on the second line (since vector is empty).

```
cout << this->adjacencyList.empty() << endl; // yeah, I'm working with graph
cout << *(this->adjacencyList[0]) << endl; // list has pointers
```

However, when I delete the second line, it shows that vector is not empty and then proceeds.
The guard for empty vectors cannot hold it and segmentation fault comes.

Do you have any ideas on this behavior? If the point is still vague, I can post my full code as an edit.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

For the one who was asking "a little more".

```
void Node :: removeEdge (string destination) // removes an edge; edge is a class that contains a pointer to another node and its weight
{
    bool deleted = false;
    cout << *this << endl; // output stream operator is overloaded for node class and is working properly - shows it's label and edges - no error for an edge
    cout << this->adjacencyList.empty() << endl;
    // cout << *(this->adjacencyList[0]) << endl; // output stream operator is overloaded for edge class - error for an edge
    if (!this->adjacencyList.empty())
    {
        for (vector <Edge *> :: iterator itr = this->adjacencyList.begin(); itr != this->adjacencyList.end(); ++itr)
        {
            if (((*itr)->getAdjacent())->getLabel() == destination) // segfault here
            {
                Edge *temp = *itr;
                this->adjacencyList.erase (itr);
                delete temp;
                deleted = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!deleted)
        throw EDGE_DOES_NOT_EXIST; // one of exceptions declared in enum somewhere in my code
}
```

SECOND EDIT:

NOTE: I cannot change headers (they were supplied by assistants), so don't ask me to change.

If you are interested in a full code, you can find here

http://pastebin.com/iCYF6hdP - Exceptions.h - all exceptions

http://pastebin.com/1fcgHGDa - Edge.h - edge class declaration

http://pastebin.com/C2DD6e3D - Edge.cpp - edge class implementation

http://pastebin.com/ZNqQ1iHE - Node.h - node class declaration

http://pastebin.com/kaVtZ3SH - Node.cpp - node class implementation

http://pastebin.com/A7Fwsi4m - Network.h - graph class declaration

http://pastebin.com/02LX0rjw - Network.cpp - graph class implementation

http://pastebin.com/MRMn0Scz - main.cpp - sample main

Comment: What is the declaration of `adjacencyList`?

Comment: adjacencyList() is a function an not a vector. As long as nobody knows what this function actually does with your vector it is hard to tell...

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, may be there is some operator overoading for <<

Comment: sorry for brackets, typo, my fault

Comment: adjacencyList is a vector of pointers

Comment: could you show us "a little more"?

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because I've missed the part about `empty()` returning `true` in the first case. When changing random code has seemingly unrelated effects, there's usually undefined behaviour or memory corruption involved.

Comment: yeah, added function implementation

Comment: empty() will likely return (_first==_last) of the vector. If you have _first == nullptr and _last != nullptr you'll get false on the empty() but dereferencing the first iterator will still segfault...

Comment: so what does second line of cout change to empty()?

Comment: There's two pointer references in the line with the segfault. One of them must is likely not valid

Comment: i think the one in adjacency list, but still what is the point of such behavior of empty()?

Comment: by the way, when i print a node, it shows edges properly, without any errors

Comment: Does vector.size() change it's behaviour accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess, that the pointer stored in the first element of your vector is invalid (perhaps `NULL`?).

So the segfault doesn't come up in `this->adjacencyList[0]` but in `*(some_invalid_pointer)`.

Try

```
Edge* firstEdge = this->adjacencyList[0];
cout << *firstEdge << endl;
```

to verify this.

**EDIT**

If the segfault happens in the first statement (the assignment), this means, that either `this` is invalid or you somehow managed to corrupt memory belonging to the internals of `vector`. For this to verify, we would have to see all code that deals with your `adjacencyList` (and I'm not sure if SO people have the time for this task ...)

**Note**

I've spotted a bug in the `removeEdge`, which is not directly related to your problem. Within the loop, you use `vector::erase` to delete the current element. This *invalidates* all iterators beyond the current one, so theoretically the rest of the loop is the infamous 'undefined behavior'(TM). In this specific case (and supposing a 'normal' standard library), this will not result in a segfault but you might miss some elements:

If you delete the current element, the current iterator (normally simply a pointer) will point to the next element. Then, the loop increment will move it to the element after this one resulting in one element not being checked.

If you have similar bugs in your code in other places, this might well result in memory corruption.

**Tip**

If you're using Microsoft C++, you can enable *checked iterators* (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). These might be able to spot this kind of bugs in your code.

**2nd EDIT** (in response to code)

You have a serious error in the `Node::operator+`.

```
Node &operator+ (Node &l, Node &r) // merges two nodes - for network merging
{
Node newNode (l.label);
    // Doing something
return newNode;
}
```

That means, you're returning *a reference to a local variable*, **never do that** :) ...

Note that, since you're using a vector of pointers, which are managed separately and released in the destructor, you cannot simply change the signature to `Node operator+(...`: in this case, the standard copy constructor would be called, which would simply copy all pointers to the result object. Then, the destructor of the local object would be called which would invalidate all pointers.

To fix this, you should implement a copy constructor on `Node` which makes real copies of all edges in the adjacency list.

Alternatively, you could use smart pointers (either `auto_ptr` resp. `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`) for the list.

Or you change the merge function to something like `Node::mergeFrom(Node& node2)` instead of overloading the `+`operator.

Concerning the original problem, you can easily end up working on an invalid `Node` instance using your current code (so the `*this`-Pointer would be invalid inside `removeEdge`)

Comment: gives segfault on the assignment

Comment: but the thing is now edge is not being deleted at all

Comment: yeah, i know about them, i would certainly change everything if i could change headers but unfortunately i can't and i guess assistants have hands growing not from the right place

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c about returning a reference in `operator+`. Show it to your assistants. Returning a reference from an addition operator is usually a bad idea ...