# Operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to write my own vector class, using overloading for certain operations such as input/output of elements and `push_back()`.

How would I overload the addition operator? Right now, I have it `cout` the individual elements of the array after summing each element of two vectors, but I would like to do something like:
 `myVector c = vec + vec2`

Then `cout << c << endl`

Would I need to write my own copy constructor?

```
myVector::myVector( myVector& v)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor called." << endl;
    this->array = new int[v.maxsize];
    this->array = v.array;
    cout << "Returning from Copy constructor." << endl;
}
```

This is my overloaded addition operator:

```
myVector myVector::operator+(myVector& a)
{
    cout << "Addition operator overloaded" << endl;
    myVector result;
    result.array = new int[a.maxsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        result.array[i] = this->array[i] + a.array[i];
    result.setSize(a.size());
    return result;

}
```

Here is the full source code:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9nkWVLwy

Comment: I created a new `myVector` object and return it. But I am getting a runtime error.

Comment: @trojansdestroy no, they don't. What would that reference refer to? They usually return by value.

Comment: How do you cope with the sizes of the two vectors being different? Also, are you following the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)?

Comment: One obvious error is the second assignment of `this->array` in your copy constructor. You leak the newly allocated memory and reuse the old pointer. Which will segfault if the copied-from is only a temporary, like the result of an arithmetic operation.

Comment: @juanchopanza Removed my poor work. Some corrent information from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2337234/2231440): "an operator whose result is a new value (such as +, -, etc) must return the new value by value, and an operator whose result is an existing value, but modified (such as <<, >>, +=, -=, etc), should return a reference to the modified value."

Comment: Are you doing this to learn or to try and do better than std::vector? If its to learn fine. Its unlikely you will do better than std::vector its relatively efficient (especially when you consider RVO NRVO and move semantics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your array (vector) is in dinamic zone of memory. When you return local object in function, you must have copy constructor , and overloaded operator=.
But in newer versions of compiler, they have optimisation, i think from standard C++11. The optimisation is that if compiler knows what he should return before running program, he wont call copy constructor.