# Why we use reference return in assignment operator overloading and not at plus-minus ops?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, return-by-reference, return-by-value

As I read in books and in the web, in C++ we can overload the "plus" or "minus" operators with these prototypes (as member functions of a `class Money`):

`const Money operator +(const Money& m2) const;`

`const Money operator -(const Money& m2) const;`

and for the assignment operator with:

`const Money& operator =(const Money& m2);`

Why use a reference to a Money object as a return value in the assignment operator overloading and not in the plus and minus operators?

Comment: If you returned a reference in a `+` or `-` binary operation, what should it refer to? It makes no sense to return a reference. The operation must create a new object.

Comment: You don't want to be able to code a + b = c;

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Returning a reference from assignment allows chaining:

```
a = b = c;  // shorter than the equivalent "b = c; a = b;"
```

(This would also work (in most cases) if the operator returned a copy of the new value, but that's generally less efficient.)

We can't return a reference from arithmetic operations, since they produce a new value. The only (sensible) way to return a new value is to return it by value.

Returning a constant value, as your example does, prevents move semantics, so don't do that.

Comment: Why? No, assignment chaining had noting to do with what is returned from assignment operator. Assignment chaining (as in your example) is possible in any version. Returning a const reference will prevent multiple modifications to lhs, as in '(a = b) = c', but that's a different story.

Comment: In other words, situations that require non-const reference returned from assignment are rather esoteric and generally belong to "bad programming practice" category for which reason one might even see some sources to explicitly *recommend* returning const reference from assignment.

Comment: @AndreyT: You're right, I was confusing myself. (Of course, you have to return something to allow chaining; but it could be a value or constant reference.)

Answer (score 10):

Because `operator+` and `operator-` don't act on *this* object, but return a new object that is the summation (or subtraction) of this object from another.

`operator=` is different because it's actually *assigning* something to this object.

`operator+=` and `operator-=` would act on this object, and are a closer analog to `operator=`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what you are asking.  You would want an expression, `a + b`, to return a reference to one of a or b, which would have the results of the expression.  Thus you would modify one of a or b to be the sum of a and b.  So you would want to redefine the semantics of the operator (+) to be the same as the operator (+=).  And like @manuell said, you would thus allow `(a + b) = c`.  The semantics you are suggesting are already offered by += and -=.

Answer (score 0):

The link shown below has better explanation I guess
[return value of operator overloading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I think its fine if you return by value in overloaded assignment operator , that is because of associativity of assignment operator. consider this:

int a = b =c = 3 ;

here associativity is as followed:
(a=(b=(c=3)))

but consider iostream operation
cout << x << y << z ;

here associativity is as followed:
(((cout << x )<< y) << z) ;

you can see that x will be printed first , so if you return by value in overloading of << operator , return value will not be "lvalue" , while returning by refrence is a lvalue , so cascading of << operator can be achieve.

one more point , copy constructor will get called if you return by value. ( which is not the case with return by refrence)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from efficiency during chained assignment (e.g., `a = b = c;`) as pointed out by the accepted answer, it is also a matter of convention. Please, refer Item 10 of Effective C++ by Scott Meyers. It is a convention followed by the built-in types and all the types in the standard library.