# Why are these two overloaded functions declared differently?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am currently reading up on overloading functions and I came across two examples in my book, but no explanation was given as to why they were differently created.

The first example overloads the "==" operator like this:

```
bool operator==(const Passenger &x, const Passenger&y){
//.......implementation details hidden
}
```

While the second example overloads the "<<" operator like this:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Passenger& pass){
//.......implementation details hidden
return out;
}
```

How come the second example uses the '&' symbol and the first one does not? Why can't we just have **ostream operator** instead of **ostream& operator**? Why doesn't bool operator use the '&'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [return value of operator overloading in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c)

Comment: The operators are unrelated  - please read some documentation

Comment: & means reference. You need to have a reference to the stream in order to chain << operators. If you didn't return a reference, but instead a copy, the original stream would not be affected by subsequent operator <<s. There's no need to this for a bool.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question really, it's just been asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the value returned by the `<<` operator to be a reference, so that it actually returns the original `ostream` object and not a copy of the object. This is why it works to string several `<<` calls together:

```
std::cout << "Hey"; // Prints "Hey" and returns cout
std::cout << passenger; // Calls custom operator and returns cout
std::cout << "What?"; // Prints "What?" and returns cout
```

Is equivalent to:

```
std::cout << "Hey" << passenger << "What?";
```

It doesn't make much sense to return a boolean by reference, since you don't expect to be able to manipulate the value returned by the `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator==(const Passenger &x, const Passenger&y)
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Passenger& pass)
```

adding spaces:

```
bool         operator==     (const Passenger &x, const Passenger&y)
ostream&     operator<<     (ostream &out, const Passenger& pass)
```

and categorizing:

```
RETURN TYPE  FUNCTION NAME  ( PARAMETERS, MORE PARAMETERS )
bool         operator==     (const Passenger &x, const Passenger&y)
ostream&     operator<<     (ostream &out, const Passenger& pass)
```

The first operator's name is `operator==`.  It returns a `bool`, and takes `(const Passenger &x, const Passenger&y)` as parameters.

The second operator's name is `operator<<`.  It returns a `ostream&` and takes `(ostream &out, const Passenger& pass)`.

A `bool` is the name of the low level boolean (`true`/`false`) type in C++.  So `==` takes two `const&` (const references) to `Passenger`s named `x` and `y` and returns `true` or `false`.

Meanwhile, `<<` takes on the left an `ostream&` (a non-const reference to an `ostream`), and takes `pass` on the right (a `const&` to a `Passenger`), and returns an `ostream&` (a non-const reference to an `ostream`).

One of the conventions of C++ is that `std::cout << a << b << c;` can be done to stream data to an `ostream`.  The operation is considered non-constant (non-`const`), and each `<<` takes an `ostream&` on the left hand side and returns it.

The compiler ends up doing: `operator<<( std::cout, a )` first.  It takes the return value, and does `operator<<( operator<<( std::cout, a ), b )`.  Etc.  The return value of each call to `<<` is used as the left-hand argument to the next call of `<<`.