# Why do we have to return by reference when overloading += operator

Tags: c++

While overloading += operator why do we have to return by reference.
for e.g. the below code also do the same thing

```
class Integer
{
  int i;
  public:
    Integer::Integer(int i):i(i){}
    void operator+=(const Integer& arg)
    {
      i = i + arg.i;
    }
};

//main.cpp
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   Integer a(10),b(20);
   b += a;
}
```

Most of the books suggest that for the above operator overloaded function should return by reference i.e as below:

```
Integer& operator+=(const Integer&)
{
    i = i + arg.i;
    return *this;
}
```

If we return by reference then what happens to the return object reference when below statement is executed:

b += a;

Comment: possible duplicate of [return value of operator overloading in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c)

Comment: `(a+=b)+=c` would do it.

Answer (score 3):

> If we return by reference then what happens to the return object
>   reference when below statement is executed:

`b += a;`

Nothing really. The statement gets executed, the reference is unused and `b` keep going on with its life.

This interesting stuff that returning by reference allows is chaining call: you cannot do `(b += b) += a` if you don't return by reference. 
This would looks like this: `(void) += const Integer &`, because `b += b` is of type `void` due to `operator+=` returning `void`.

Answer (score 1):

So that `T& x = (y += z);` works consistently with fundamental types.

Comment: Wouldn't the void operator+=(const Integer& arg) will also work as expected.

Comment: No, because you cannot initialise `T& x;` with an expression of type `void`.