# Why does operator<< of istream class have return/parameter type of reference in C++?

Tags: c++, ostream, istream

I'm studying the overloading of operator<< and operator>>.

So I must use istream/ostream class to override.

But I don't understand why overridden operators take istream/ostream object by reference and return a reference.

Can you explain this?

Comment: Possible dupe / at least relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c

Comment: I am sure this is a dupe, but just can't find the original link!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return value of operator overloading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It is done because stream types are not copyable and so that you can stack operations. std::cin >> num1 >> num2; and the like.

Comment: If stream types are not copyable, their type cannot be anything except reference?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir meant that stream-based types such as `std::cin` and `std::cout` are not copyable - their copy constructor is deleted. So when the compiler tries to find a matching `operator<<(x,y)` function, if a defined function is `operator<<(std::cout, int)` then the compiler would have to make a copy of `std::cout` for the first argument, which is not possible, so it would fail to match. By making it a reference, the compiler does not need to make a copy of `std::cout` and can then match successfully.

Comment: Thank u for kind answer @hadriel!