# Why does my operator + overload call my copy constructor despite being passed by reference?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I've done some research, but I have not been able to find an explanation for the behavior of my code (I may not be asking the right questions). I'm working in C++, using VS2019.

The code regards the `Points` class found in the Data Structures and Other Objects textbook.

**My class as it exists now:**

```
class point {
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    //constructors
    point(double ix = 0.0, double iy = 0.0) {
        x = ix;
        y = iy;
    }
    point(const point &z) {
        x = z.getX();
        y = z.getY();
        cout << "copy constructor triggered" << endl;
        cout << x << "," << y << endl;
    }

    //assignment
    void operator = (const point& result) {
        x = result.getX();
        y = result.getY();
        cout << "assignment overload triggered" << endl;
        cout << x << "," << y << endl;
    }

    //getters
    double getX() const {
        return x;
    }
    double getY() const{
        return y;
    }

    //setters
    void setX(double newX) {
        x = newX;
    }
    void setY(double newY) {
        y = newY;
    } //other function members are omitted
}//end point() class

point operator + (const point& A, const point& B) { //Adds x1 to x2, y1 to y2
    point n;

    n.setX(A.getX()+ B.getX());
    n.setY(A.getY()+ B.getY());
    return n;
}
```

The problem first arose when I found that I could not create an instance of a class on the same line as I tried to add two instances using the operator+ overload.

```
point p1(5, 3);
point p2(12, 9);
point p3 = p1 + p2; //gives the following error: class "point" has no suitable copy constructor
```

I found I had made an error by forgetting to include "const" in my copy constructor. By resolving that issue with the copy constructor I was able to get the code working well enough to submit my assignment, but I wasn't satisfied with my understanding.

In the process of resolving that issue, I'd also added the assignment operator overload (=) inside the class definition. Running through some console debugging, I found a strange pattern:

```
point p1(5, 3);
point p2(12, 9);
point p3;
p3 = p1 + p2; //calls both copy constructor and assignment instructor
point p4 = p1 + p2; // calls only copy constructor

point p5;
p5 = p1; //calls only assignment operator
point p6 = p2; // calls only copy constructor
```

So now, I'm wondering **why p3 = p1 + p2 calls both the copy constructor and the assignment overload.** Is the compiler calling the copy constructor when adding the points? I didn't think it would be since the `operator+` overload creates a temp point with the default constructor then manually changes the values with getters and setters, then returns that temp point. My understanding is that the copy constructor should only be called when *creating a new object*, which `p3` is not.

I should also say that we have not yet discussed using pointers with classes/objects.

Any help here is appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Your assignment operator should be returning a reference to the current object, not `void`.

Comment: In addition to what @PaulMcKenzie mentioned (`void operator=(const point& result)` should be `point& operator=(const point& result)`) - start with the member function `operator+=` and the free function `operator+` will be a breeze.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CM5YNVhExxiM0RaB), looks like MSVC is not doing copy elision as it should.

Comment: @PaulSanders Maybe running a "debug" build instead of a release build?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Maybe.  gcc appears not to care.

Comment: From what I remember, VS 2019 requires you to turn on the C++17 support manually, so maybe that is another reason for the copy elision to not occur.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will review my assignment operator, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a temporary point and changing its values will not call the copy constructor.

You are returning an object here, not a pointer or a reference to an object:

```
point operator + (const point& A, const point& B) { //Adds x1 to x2, y1 to y2
```

when you return from your function a new object is created from the one that you had inside your function and this is where the copy constructor gets called.

Comment: Could NRVO prevent this copy?

Comment: @Jeffrey Since C++17, it's a guarantee if made correctly. `A` will be copied - the returned value will not)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So I was looking for a way to pass back the operator overload by reference and I found that when a new value is created, operator overloads like + are passed by value:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337213/return-value-of-operator-overloading-in-c

Is it impossible to return the + operator by reference? I assume an unnecessary copy of a very large object would be computationally taxing. Is adding one object to another better done as a member function to avoid that copy constructor?

Comment: @boddha In `A = B + C` you don't want `B` or `C` to change, right? I'mplement `operator+=` first.

Comment: @boddha *So I was looking for a way to pass back the operator overload by reference* -- Don't try and outsmart the compiler with tricks.  More times than not, the trick backfires and slower code is produced.  Also, C++ is based on value-semantics, not reference-semantics.  It does not work like Java or other languages, where `=` doesn't really mean `=`.  The `=` works (or should work) the same way for `int`, `double`, `float`, as it does for `std::string`, `YourClass`, etc.

Comment: This explanation makes sense, but here is what I realized when I debugged a similar piece of code of mine (overloading + operator): The copy constructor is called right before the first line of the overloading function, not after we return from the function. Any idea?